# TextMeshPro batching unity

Tags: unity, batching, text-mesh-pro

I have several GameObject with textMeshPro component attached to them, each one of them draw themselves individually resulting in a lot of draw call is there any way to batch them?
Each one of them comes from the same prefab and none of theres attributes other than text are being modified. These are not the UI Version of the TextMeshPro.

Comment: Same issue here. Have them on same Z value, static etc. All the things that should be done to make it batch. But they're not.

Comment: @Confused Just a guess: do they use the same font? If some characters are not included by the font, they will use the fallback font, which will break the batching.

Comment: Everything single thing is the same. Am isolating to make this work. Yet it isn't working. Documents (from the past) strongly indicate it should work. @Mangata